# Heartbeat to check if a user is authenticated?

Tags: authentication, programming-languages, heartbeat

Googling for heartbeat authentication gives so much info that inst related that makes it hard to find good sources.

In short terms what a heart beat authentication is ?

In what cases could would it be more applied to be used ?

I am sorry that this seems like a ultra general question if you could perhaps direct me to some better information about it I could make my question more specific to what I am aiming for, but for that I need to know more about heartbeat.

Comment: What problem (that you think heartbeat authentication would be appropriate for) are you trying to solve?

Comment: You refering to this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(program)  or are you talking about some type of heartbeat to check to see if a user is authenticated?

Comment: @Nix `are you talking about some type of heartbeat to check to see if a user is authenticated?` exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the site works, the heartbeat functionality could be as simple as performing an Ajax `GET` on the site, then testing the HTTP status of the response.  For example, a `200` may mean that the browser was authenticated, and a `401` could mean that the user's authorization has expired.  Or perhaps the site redirects the request to a login page, in which case you could check for a `302`.

Here's how you could do it via jQuery, for example:

```
setInterval(
    function() {
        jQuery.ajax(
            '/protected-resource', 
            {
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (jqXHR.status != 200) {
                        doUnauthorizedResponse();
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    },
    60000);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, so basicly a heartbeat for authentication is a way to make sure the user have a valid session otherwise boot him out ? What I have is a desktop application that auth using https to my website, so a heartbeat in this case would be the same as checking every X minutes if the server can communicate with the client or not ?